# Query of five tables that have complicated relation

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. Here's an example

**`table_one`**

```
-------------------------------------
id    |   username    |    group    |
-------------------------------------
1     |     user      |      1      |
-------------------------------------
```

**`table_two`**

```
----------------------
groupid|   groupname |
----------------------
  1    | superadmin  |
----------------------
```

**`table_three`**

```
----------------------------------
id    |  rights    |   groupid   |
----------------------------------
1     |     1      |       1     |
----------------------------------
2     |      2     |       1     |
----------------------------------
```

**`table_four`**

```
---------------------------------------------
  rights    |   name                        |
---------------------------------------------
     1      |  adminforfirsttdepartment     |
---------------------------------------------
     2      |  adminforseconddepartment     |
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the `username` and `id` also the `group` information of that `username` and also all the `rights` where the `group` is that for the `group` of the `user` (or simply where `groupie` = `user`'s `groupid`) then the `name` of the `rights` thats assigned on the `user`.

Is it possible to have just one query for this?

Comment: Do groups always have at least one right? Also, can you edit your question to replace "table_one" etc with the actual table names so your question makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and don't forget to change the `:id` in `where` condition.

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.username, 
       t4.name 
FROM   table_one t1 
       INNER JOIN table_two t2 
               ON t1.group = t2.groupid 
       INNER JOIN table_three t3 
               ON t2.groupid = t3.groupid 
       INNER JOIN table_four t4 
               ON t3.rights = t4.rights 
WHERE  t1.id = :id
```

Note: Change `where` condition as per your requirement.

Comment: what does `= :id` in `WHERE  t1.id = :id ` mean?

Comment: I got this error `Not unique table/alias: 'user_rights'` why is it? i think i have no error in my table name.